# Create a table view depending on values in second table by adding the dates of that table and subtracting the result on first table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Open to either Create View or Update Queries.

I have two tables as below. One showing detention and the other shows a starting detention limit for a student. Both table contains row ID as Primary Key. ID below is not a PK.

```
      Table1: Detention                        |     Table2: TotalDetention
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PK  ID    startDate    endDate     status      |   PK    ID    totalDetention
1    1   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Pending     |   1     1          28
2    2   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Pending     |   2     2          28
3    3   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Declined    |   3     3          28
4    1   2016-10-01   2016-10-05   Declined    |   4     10         28
5    1   2016-10-05   2016-10-10   Pending     |
```

When the status of Detention is set to 'Approved', I want to get the total days from startDate and endDate then subtract that number from TotalDetention, in a view if possible.

Result would look like this.

```
      Table1: Detention                        |     Table2: TotalDetention
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PK  ID    startDate    endDate     status      |   PK    ID    totalDetention
1    1   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Approved    |   1     1          17
2    2   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Pending     |   2     2          28
3    3   2016-09-23   2016-09-29   Declined    |   3     3          28
4    1   2016-10-01   2016-10-05   Declined    |   4     10         28
5    1   2016-10-05   2016-10-10   Approved    |
```

Comment: From 2016-09-23 to  2016-09-29 is 6 days not 7 ? Just to be sure i understand what you want :)

Comment: what about `DATEDIFF`

Comment: @M.Grue Ah yes I'll edit it now :P

Comment: @Nebi I am aware of DATEDIFF but unsure how to tie it all together

Comment: I understand that the view you are expecting should contain only what is shown in Table2 (that is ID and totalDetention)?

Comment: If you expect a view, then "Update a table depending..." title for your question is rather misleading.

Comment: Don't let table data depend on UPDATE using other columns like this, you'll only get data inconsistency. Either use triggers, or a computed column.

Comment: Is it possible for a single ID in Table1 to have multiple detentions?

Comment: Is ID a Primary Key?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, Yes there can be multiple ID in table 1, theres a row id as primary key isntead.

Comment: @JonesJoseph both ID are foreign keys of another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your title(update a table)..you can do this using update trigger on table1..

```
create trigger updatedata
    on dbo.table1
    after update as
    begin
  if (update(status)) and exists(select * from inserted where status='approved')
    Begin
    update t2
    set t2.totaldetention=t2.totaldetention-datediff(day,i.startddate,i.enddate)
    from table2 t2
    join
    inserted i
    on i.id=t2.id and i.status='approved'

    end
    end
```

Comment: initially ,i missed status='approved' check,thats why may be

Comment: there is no column `t2.detention`.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek:When you scribble out sample data,there might be some misses,updated now

Comment: So now this basically works in such way, that every time I update Table1, the value of `totaldetention` is decremented. If I update table twice, value is decremented twice... etc.

Comment: If I update two rows at once, one is 'approved' and the other is 'rejected' - both IDs get updated anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    D.Id
    ,TD.TotalDetention - DATEDIFF(d, D.StartDate, D.EndDate) AS LeftOverDetention
FROM Detention D
INNER JOIN 
TotalDetention TD ON TD.Id = D.Id
WHERE D.status = 'Approved'
```

Then use it in UPDATE statement.
Or try this.

```
UPDATE TotalDetention
SET TotalDetention = TotalDetention - DATEDIFF(d, D.StartDate, D.EndDate)
FROM TotalDetention TD
INNER JOIN
Detention D
ON D.Id = TD.Id
WHERE D.Status = 'Approved'
```

Based on updates provided in the question's comments I think you need this:

```
SELECT 
    TD.Id
    ,TD.TotalDetention - isnull(D.Detained, 0) AS LeftOverDetention
FROM TotalDetention TD
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        Id
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(d, startDate, endDate)) Detained
    FROM Detention
    WHERE status = 'Approved'
    GROUP BY Id
) AS D ON D.Id = TD.Id
```

Forgot to mention the join condition. My fault :(

Comment: This `UPDATE`-Statement would always apply to `status = 'Approved'` when the Update is run. So the TotalDetention would decrease every time you run the update.

Comment: The question title said he wanted to update the table so I provided the UPDATE statement.

Comment: but a trigger is the key then. Just because of the fact you only want to update the row you just got `status = 'Approved'`.

Comment: This would even happen if you have trigger. If I update TotalDetention based on update in table Detention inside a trigger then every time Detention is updated TotalDentention would be updated and thus same effect.

Comment: @TheShooter Could you tell me what the D is on the last one after Join? I'm getting error on it.

Comment: It is alias given to the sub query. Instead of D try using AS D. It should work.

Comment: @TheShooter I get this error. 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,'

Comment: @NLimbu: Sorry it was my mistake forgot to add the join condition. Updated the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
SELECT t.*, t1.id, CASE WHEN t.status = 'Approved' THEN 
(totalDetention-DATEDIFF(dd, startDate, endDate)) 
ELSE 
    totalDetention 
END totalDetention
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN table2 t1 ON t1.id = t.id
```

Comment: This won't work correctly with multiple IDs repeated in Table1. :(

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I got so excited after trying one row. you are right :(

Comment: Please see the last TheShoote's answer here - it could be more concise but it's OK.

Comment: @NLimbu, Can you please change sample and desired output data accordingly. you guys are talking about what if both table contains multiple rows with same id ? or only one table ?